# I want to send Int over output stream using outputStream.write() in swift

Tags: swift, tcp, swift4, serversocket

I have to send the `length of a byte array` over output stream,
below is the code I used and I'm getting this error:

> "Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer' to expected
>   argument type 'UnsafePointer<_>'"

```
withUnsafePointer(to: &len) { (pointer: UnsafePointer<Int>) -> Void in
    outputStream.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(pointer), maxLength: 4)
}
```

If somebody can tell me where I am going wrong or suggest an alternate method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to send 4 bytes to the OutputStream in the host order, you should better declare the var as `Int32`, not `Int`.

And your code uses the way of converting pointer type once found in some ancient Swift.

Try this:

```
var len4 = Int32(len)
withUnsafeBytes(of: &len4) { bufPtr in
    outputStream.write(bufPtr.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), maxLength: bufPtr.count)
}
```

Or, if you want to send 4 bytes in the network order, as the tags are suggesting, you may need to modify the above code a little bit.

```
var len4 = Int32(len).bigEndian
withUnsafeBytes(of: &len4) { bufPtr in
    outputStream.write(bufPtr.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), maxLength: bufPtr.count)
}
```